# Codeigniter form model for agree terms

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I have codeigniter form for my agree terms, but my form errors will not show up unless I have a model.

Is there a model that I can use for agree terms checked box. Not sure what to add for model for agree terms.

This is what done so far.

**Controller part**

```
public function index() {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('terms', 'Agree to License', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {
            $data = array();
            $data['heading_step_1'] = $this->lang->line('heading_step_1');
            $data['heading_step_1_small'] = $this->lang->line('heading_step_1_small');
            $data['text_license'] = $this->lang->line('text_license');
            $data['text_installation'] = $this->lang->line('text_installation');
            $data['text_configuration'] = $this->lang->line('text_configuration');
            $data['text_finished'] = $this->lang->line('text_finished');
            $data['text_project'] = $this->lang->line('text_project');
            $data['text_documentation'] = $this->lang->line('text_documentation');
            $data['text_footer'] = $this->lang->line('text_footer');
            $data['text_support'] = $this->lang->line('text_support');
            $data['button_continue'] = $this->lang->line('button_continue');
            $data['text_terms'] = $this->lang->line('text_terms');

            $this->load->view('template/stage_1', $data);
        } else {
            redirect('install/stage_2');
        }

    }
```

**view part**

```
     <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<?php echo form_open('install/stage_1/index');?>
<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">', '</p>'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="terms"  scroll; height: 550px;"><?php echo $text_terms; ?></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<?php
$data = array(
    'name'  => 'terms',
    'id'          => 'terms',
    'value'       => '1',
    'checked'     => FALSE,
    'style' => 'margin-right: 10px;'
    );

echo form_checkbox($data);
$data = array(
    'value'       => $button_continue,
    'role'       => 'button',
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
    );
echo form_submit($data);
?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accept', 'Agree to License', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'You must agree to the license before you can install CMS Canvas!');

if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
     redirect('install/stage_2'); 
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('template/stage_1', $data);
}
```

Comment: Does not load because needs a model I have all ready tried both ways. Just trying to work model out but not sure what to add for a model for agree terms.

Comment: you can use this directly in your controller. no need a model.

Comment: I have my validation errors to show in view but do not load

Comment: is $data array setted before in controller ?. Is there any $data['x'] = ?

Comment: Yes above the library there are data[] = ;

Answer (score 0):

### Extend Form Validation Library

**application/libraries**

```
MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function checkboxIsOn($value)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkboxIsOn', '...message...');
        return ($value == 'on') ? true : false;
    }
}
```

---

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accept', 'Agree to License', 'trim|checkboxIsOn');
```

---

If you want to exclude the accept field, don't use a `mass assignment` method, just `@unset()` it once its validated

Comment: Gave it ago not work. Seems to only work when include a model, but do not know what model should use for it.

Comment: You don't need a Model to Validate user input(form).

Comment: I have tried both ways not working no errors showing up on views but names are correct very strange. All data ok. And I use HMVC

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. I had to remove the "else" part of the form now validation working seems codeigniter user guide not correct some times.

```
public function agree() {
        $data = array();

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('accept', 'Agree to License', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'You must agree to the license before you can install!');

      if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            redirect('install/step2');
      }

      $data = array();
        $data['heading_step_1'] = $this->lang->line('heading_step_1');
        $data['heading_step_1_small'] = $this->lang->line('heading_step_1_small');
        $data['text_license'] = $this->lang->line('text_license');
        $data['text_installation'] = $this->lang->line('text_installation');
        $data['text_configuration'] = $this->lang->line('text_configuration');
        $data['text_finished'] = $this->lang->line('text_finished');
        $data['text_project'] = $this->lang->line('text_project');
        $data['text_documentation'] = $this->lang->line('text_documentation');
        $data['text_footer'] = $this->lang->line('text_footer');
        $data['text_support'] = $this->lang->line('text_support');
        $data['button_continue'] = $this->lang->line('button_continue');
        $data['text_terms'] = $this->lang->line('text_terms');

        $this->load->view('template/stage_1', $data);

        }
```